# I'm having a problem with locale and locale-gen in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, locale

I'm having some trouble with locale settings. I'm getting an error like this when I type **locale** in terminal:

```
$locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I need your guys help. When I type locale-gen in terminal, I'm  getting an error:

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
Generation complete.
```

I found a solution somehow I figured it out myself. I deleted the # 
in /etc/locale.gen in the last line. It was like down below before I delete:

```
# aa_DJ ISO-8859-1
# aa_DJ.UTF-8 UTF-8
# aa_ER UTF-8
# aa_ER@saaho UTF-8
...
# zu_ZA ISO-8859-1
# zu_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

I changed the last line like this:

```
# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

I don't know if I did something something wrong but when I did this, the error solved. Please tell me if I did something wrong. After that
I tried to reconfigure the locales but I get an another error when I try to do:

```
$sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

And one more error I'm getting when I try to change LC_ALL with:

```
$export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8"
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

I'm getting an error but LC_ALL changes.
I don't know what happened to my locale settings but it seems like I really messed it up. What should I do to fix all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your locale exist using:

```
locale -a
```

If you don't see your locale on the list, then use:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Then update your locales to existing locale by:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Apply changes by:

```
. /etc/default/locale
```

My locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Setting locale for current session:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

You could also try

```
$ sudo apt purge locales && sudo apt install locales
```

Comment: I will try that when I have time. Can I ask you something? Did I do something wrong with adding # in /etc/locale.gen in last line?

Comment: *No*, but at the start of file it says that you need to rerun `locale-gen` after changing that list. It's the same if you would run `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` I think.

Comment: I'm afraid to say but I am having an error again when I run `sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` 
Error is:
`$sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Please, show what your `locale -a` displays

Comment: Sure, 
`$locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
`
The en_US.UTF-8 is missing and I tried to add it with locale-gen command but still didn't work

Comment: Try: `$ sudo apt purge locales && sudo apt install locales`

Comment: Have you tried both commands: `sudo locale-gen en_US &&
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: I tried it right now and nothing changed in locale -a

Comment: OK, have you tried the last command for locales reinstalling?

Comment: And I purged all of them right now, when I type locale -a it shows every one of them and yeah it is fixed. Thank you so much @Gryu you guys make this community really useful. I owe you one

Comment: Thank you too:), You're welcome)

Comment: i did everything here and my LANGUAGE= is still blank